# Fitting van der waals law on real data

Tags: thermodynamics, specific-reference

For an examples class on thermodynamics, I would like to fit [Van der Waals law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation)  on data of real gasses, say $CO_2, H_2O_2, CH_4$.

I want to set out measurements of pressure and volume at constant temperature in a P-V diagram, and make a fit to determine the van der Waals parameters a and b. 
Only I have no idea where to look for experimental data.

Is such data available in databases or articles?

Would I have to extract them by hand from plots or are there (electronic) tables available? Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Maybe these tables will be of use for your project http://thermo.sdsu.edu/testhome/Test/solve/basics/tables/tables.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best single source is at NIST.  The data is located at the [chemistry webbook](http://webbook.nist.gov/chemistry/).  Once you are at that site click on formula or name under "general searches".  You can not only get all the data you want in a downloadable format, it will even graph it for you

Enjoy yourself.  There is no better way to learn about data than to work with it.

Comment: @Gans Thanks for the link. If you take H2, where can you find measurements of pressure and vollume for the gas at constant temperature? I couln't find such a table under "Gas phase thermochemistry data".

Comment: You have to go to the fluid properties section.

Comment: @FrenchKheldar thank you. This is an wonderful resource for my classes!